# R - How to get specific attributes in XML using xmlEventParse()

Tags: r, xml, sax

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<posts>
  <row Id="1" PostTypeId="1" 
       AcceptedAnswerId="15" CreationDate="2010-07-19T19:12:12.510" Score="27" 
       ViewCount="1647" Body="some text;" OwnerUserId="8" 
       LastActivityDate="2010-09-15T21:08:26.077" 
       Title="title" AnswerCount="5" CommentCount="1" FavoriteCount="17" />
[...]
```

For example, I'd like to get the script to output "ViewCount : 1647".

```
library(XML)

fileName <- "test.xml"
startElement = function(name, attrs, .state)  {
  if(name == "row"){
    .state = .state + 1
    #cat("ViewCount: ", xmlAttrs(gg)["ViewCount"]) <- **output result here**
  }
  if(.state == 10){
    cat("Total Row Parsed: ".state , "\n")
  }
  .state
}
gg <- xmlEventParse(fileName, handlers = list(startElement = startElement), state = 0)
print(gg)
```

Have been looking up the internet, but the examples are too sparse and complicated.

Is there any way to get the attributes simply like in Python

```
viewCount = attributes["ViewCount"]?
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4):

You can use ***xpathApply*** function of **XML library** to do the same in a single line.

Check out this code.

```
library(XML)
a <- xmlParse('<posts>
                <row Id="1" PostTypeId="1" 
              AcceptedAnswerId="15" CreationDate="2010-07-19T19:12:12.510" Score="27" 
              ViewCount="1647" Body="some text;" OwnerUserId="8" 
              LastActivityDate="2010-09-15T21:08:26.077" 
              Title="title" AnswerCount="5" CommentCount="1" FavoriteCount="17" /> </posts>')
xpathApply(a,"/posts/row",xmlGetAttr,"ViewCount")[[1]]
```

Comment: Adding some context around your code would seriously improve your answer.

Comment: What if I MUST use xmlEventParse() because the file is like 50GB++? Can I still use xpath?

Comment: Yes as your file size is very large then you must use xmlEventParse and yes after that you can apply xpath function. I have near tried with as this such large files but otherwise it was worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The xml2 library can provide a simpler syntax than the xml library.  There an alternative solution using the xml2 library:

```
library(xml2)

doc<-read_xml('<posts>
  <row Id="1" PostTypeId="1" 
              AcceptedAnswerId="15" CreationDate="2010-07-19T19:12:12.510" Score="27" 
              ViewCount="1647" Body="some text;" OwnerUserId="8" 
              LastActivityDate="2010-09-15T21:08:26.077" 
              Title="title" AnswerCount="5" CommentCount="1" FavoriteCount="17" /></posts>')

#find all of the "row" nodes
row<-xml_find_all(doc, "row")

#find attribute of interest in the nodes
xml_attr(row, "ViewCount")
```